# Error signing Distribution iOS app "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer"

Tags: ios, iphone, codenameone

I generated my distribution certificates ok, but when I send the app to codenameone to build it, throws this erros on log.

```
Signing Identity:     "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXXX"
Provisioning Profile: "IOS_DISTRIBUTION_Profile"
                      (647b6c28-7bd7-424f-bf1b-5e8081d7f9b8)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 35998CCB7538F0F2EB73795C4F444C1DD2EC4986 --entitlements /Volumes/MacintoshHD2/temp/build1022640200136408778xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/App.app.xcent /Volumes/MacintoshHD2/temp/build1022640200136408778xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app

Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX"

/Volumes/MacintoshHD2/temp/build1022640200136408778xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Regards

Comment: How did you generate the certificate?
Did you use the wizard or did you do it manually? If the latter, what were the steps you took?

Comment: Hi Shai, I tried the three ways: 1) I tried to generate the prod certificate with the wizard, but did not generate it, The wizard screen was in white and hangs it. 2) I generated the certificate on the Apple developer site, first of all I generated with a Mac a certificate request, and export it to the mac, then I export to a p12 extension, then I generated a profile. 3) I generated it with the Xcode, then export it to p12, and on the developer site generate the prod profile. Any of the three ways did not work. Recently I updated OSX to the Big Surm today I will try with Catalina, Regards

Comment: Hi Shai, when I try to generate with codenameone I got this error: REST request failed due to internal CLI failure. See server error
log.762f1c33-9ff5-4401-b8d2-2803cba552b

Comment: Hi Shai, I tried a lot of methods to generate the certificate, I have eve tried with windows (https://gist.github.com/jcward/d08b33fc3e6c5f90c18437956e5ccc35) and with the voltBuild signer (https://volt.build/certificate/). The resutl is always the same. I think may be an error on codenameone compiler server, have you read it?  (https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/) perhaps the problem are on the codenameOne certificates. May be? Regards

Comment: Hi Shai, I found more information for this error: (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131088), may be you need to install de new certificates (WWDR) https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ Regards

Comment: Do you have more than one device connected to 2-factor authentication?
If so reduce this to one device only and try the wizard again.It should work. The other methods are much harder.

Comment: Yes Shai, and I receibed ok the code on the secondary terminal, CodenameOne ask me for the code, when I entered it codenameone throws the error (REST request failed due to internal CLI failure. See server error log.762f1c33-9ff5-4401-b8d2-2803cba552b ). I ask to apple and they said that I must to check the root certificate on my compile enviroment. :-(. Is important to us resolve this. Regards

Comment: You need to have only one device connected. Otherwise the wizard won't work. It seems this is happening to some people and the workarounds are a bit painful https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16108 . E.g. logging out of all apple registered devices, changing the password, and then trying again.

Comment: Hi Shai, I have only one device associated to the account, but is not the principal problem. I always generate my certificates on Apple developers page and don't have any problem. The problem is with the new certificates generated. Did you have installed it on your platforms?

Comment: Hi Shai, please read this. https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

Comment: We're aware of that. We're working on updating without breaking current builds but right now the certificate wizard should still work

Comment: Hi Shai, I don't use the certificate wizard, I directly on Apple developer site or Xcode. I can signing on my local computer after installed  the certificate (https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer). We can compile on codenameOne with certificates generated before September 1, 2020, but not with the new certificates. Before I uptate my laptop we were getting the same error that we get on CodenameOne dashboard, so I think you must to install it, Apple explain the error on this link (https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/) Regards and sorry for my insistence.

Comment: If you do use the wizard it should work for now. We plan to add the certificates to all the servers on Monday. We waited with this until after the 7.0 release code freeze.

Comment: Hi Shai, I tried a lot of ways to enter on wizard bau not be able, I can wait, I will try on tuesday. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Shai, today works, I suposed you have updated the certificates, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autorespond:

The problem was on the compile machine certificates, read this: https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

You must to install on the machine where you compile this certificate: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer

On CodenameOne, when the codenameOne team updated the certificate works again.

Regards